# How to extract information from multiple json files using python

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I have multiple json files in a folder. I had implemented a way to catch only .json files in this folder. My problem is: I need to extract some information contained in each of those files but it didn't work the way I expected. I need to find a way to get this information and convert all into a pandas dataframe.

The variable *jsons_data* contains all .json files

```
jsons_data = json_import(path_to_json)

for index, js in enumerate(jsons_data):
    with open(os.path.join(path_to_json, js)) as json_file:
        data = json.loads(json_file)

print(data)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem in your code is that on every iteration you override the content of `data`.

I assume you want to create on big dataframe from all the files in that case you can do -

```
dataframes = []
for js in jsons_data:
    dataframes.append(pd.read_json(os.path.join(path_to_json, js)))
df = pd.concat(dataframes)
```

See documentation about read_json -
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3.0rc1/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html

Comment: Yes, that is what i want to do but i tried you code and didn't worked, instead of this had returned an error "all arrays must be of the same length". Here it's a image showing the list o .json files i have https://imgur.com/a/mNpallS

Comment: Do all the json files have the same format?

Comment: Yes, all have the same format

Comment: It is hard for me to answer without having a look in the data itself but I tend to think that one of the files might have an extra column or something like that

Comment: Here goes one of those .json files https://gist.github.com/feliperoque/2d708597a5b62feb8570a6c8582717c8

Comment: if one of them have something wrong, is there a way to check who it's?

Comment: I would debug by going over `dataframes` and printing the columns of each dataframe. You can do it inside the loop `for js in jsons_data: df = pd.read_json(...); print (js, df.columns)`
If you see something strange try to figure it out

Comment: i was wondering here if a need to convert those .json in dataframe before the for loop...?

Comment: Doing `pd.read_json` read the files as dataframes

Comment: I did  `for js in jsons_data: df = pd.read_json((os.path.join(path_to_json, js))), print(js, df.columns)` and didn't worked...returned the same error as before